# How to set and ENV variable in airflow like dev/qa/prod?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, environment-variables, airflow

I want to set an Env variable in airflow which I can later use in my pipeline. I need it to identify the metadata.

Like if `$ENV == 'dev'` use `s3-dev-bucket`
if `$ENV == 'prod'` use `s3-prod-bucket` which will be identified by `s3-$ENV-bucket`.

I have tried putting it in variables from airflow UI but the variable's value turns invalid after some time. It would be great if someone can help with a reliable method for this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you enter the s3 bucket details as part of the connection configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options here:

1. As Simon D suggested, the best solution would be to make that part of the connection. Then per airflow environment, you would have the same connection id but different credentials and end-points.
2. You could use Airflow variables. However, you mentioned they turn invalid. I am unaware with any bugs why the variable value could turn invalid. Maybe good to have a look at that.
3. You could use environment variables. Not sure how you are running airflow but this is also an option.